# Best way to do recursive joins?

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the best way to do recursive joins in Oracle? Assuming I have a schema as follows:

```
node:
  id: number
  parent_id: number
  name: string
```

How would I join a child node with all its parents?

I've tried the following but it fails:

```
SELECT c.* from node LEFT JOIN(
  SELECT * FROM node c
  START WITH id = c.id
  CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
) ON 1 = 1
```

It is complaining about the START WITH id = c.id part.

Comment: What is "c"? You don't define it. Also, can you give an example table and the expected query result?

Comment: Sorry, meant to put the c after node, still having the issue.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you give us some sample data and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need a start point of where to start ,so there will be one id which does not have `parent_id` and its `null`,so what i did it here to explain id 1 does not have parent_id .

```
create table node (id number,parent_id number,name varchar2(200));

insert into node values(1,null,'king');
insert into node values(2,1,'gaurav');
insert into node values(3,1,'rohan');
insert into node values(4,2,'anshoo');
insert into node values(5,4,'ajay');

 select id,parent_id,name from node 
 start with parent_id is null 
 connect by prior id= parent_id;
```

sqlfiddle  [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0cce5/1)

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to say what you are really trying to achieve based on the information you have provided in you question, but it seems to me you want to display sub-trees for each `ID`(Main tree starting from ID=1, lets order them that way, then sub-tree starting from ID=2 and so on all the way down).

Here is an example:

```
with Tb_Table (id, parent_id, name) as(
  select 1, 1, 'Child_1' from dual union all
  select 2, 1, 'Child_2' from dual union all
  select 3, 3, 'Child_3' from dual
),
rec_data (id, parent_id, name, lv) as(
  select id
       , parent_id
       , name
       , 0 lv
   from  Tb_Table  
  where id = id

  union all

  select tt.id
       , tt.parent_id
       , tt.name 
       , lv + 1
   from rec_data rt
   join tb_table tt
     on (rt.id = tt.parent_id)   
)
search depth first by id set ord
cycle id set is_cycle to 'Y' default 'N'
select id
     , parent_id
     , concat(lpad(' ', lv*3,' '), name) name
  from rec_data
```

result:

```
Id Parent_Id   Name 
-----------------------   
1     1        Child_1 
1     1          Child_1 
2     1          Child_2 
2     1        Child_2 
3     3        Child_3 
3     3          Child_3
```

[**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0725d/4)

Answer (score 0):

`c` is somewhere in the join and cannot be reached outside the brackets, but I think you should really step by step learn how to use `connect by`. Honestly this link helped me to learn and understand it: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/connect_by.html

Answer (score -4):

in SQL Server (which it looks like you're using) recursive queries are supported.  Take my example below where a user is assigned to many locations.  Each of those locations can have a parent locations.  This query returns all the locations plus child locations that @userID is assigned to.

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf_UserLocations_Recursive] 
(   
    @UserID uniqueidentifier
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH recusrive (LocationID)
    AS (
        --anchor
        SELECT LocationID
        FROM LocationUser lu
        WHERE lu.Aspnet_Userid = @userID
        UNION ALL
        -- Recursive member definition
        SELECT child.LocationID         
        FROM recusrive parent
            INNER JOIN Location child ON (parent.LocationID = child.LocationParentID)
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM recusrive
)
```